# Are these problems symptoms of a broken motherboard?

Tags: boot, cpu, bios, hardware-failure, dell-latitude

I've got a Latitude E5500 That has been apparently been sitting in a box for a few years.

Lady gave it to me, said it would never boot up. As I suspected, the bios battery was dead. I yoinked it out and it started right up. I told her I would get her another battery and sort out some other stuff on the computer.

I booted it in safe mode, and left it running for a bit. When I came back, it was dead. Turned it back on and this time it died shortly after start up.

There is a blinking combo that in the user manual says it means the processor is dead. Okay fine, an extra $20, no worries. So I swapped the old intel core 2 duo for another and I got the same error combo. I then put the old IC2D in to a laptop I know works, that booted fine.

What happened to the Lattitude? Could the motherboard be dead?

Comment: Its possible.  Your guess is good as ours

Answer (score 1):

**You need to run the Dell on-board diagnostics.**  If you can keep the laptop booted up long enough, run the diagnostics by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> at the BIOS splash screen, then choose the `Diagnostics` startup option. The diagnostics will test the CPU, motherboard, memory, and other critical components of the laptop.

After running an initial diagnostics test, taking perhaps 10-15 minutes, you may be offered to run an *Extended* diagnostics.  Do so, especially if the short test doesn't turn up any errors.

If the Extended diagnostics don't find anything, look for an option to run tests on the motherboard, CPU, memory, etc. **multiple times**.  This will help you catch intermittent problems that might not be discovered by running the diagnostics only once.